# mod mono consuming lots of memory and cpu in some situations. How to improve this?

Tags: apache-2.2, cpu-usage, mono

I have set up a apache + mod_mono asp.net mvc3 website, and I'm facing some strange problems with it.

Some times, for a reason I do not know, the website just stops responding.
When this happens, I ssh into my Linode account (where I host my website) and run "top", only to verify that the mono process is using up to 400% CPU (how is that even possible? Virtualization, maybe?) and lots of memory.
This is, supposedly, a known issue ([see this](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono#Under_high_load.2C_mono_process_consumes_a_lot_of_memory.2C_website_stops_responding)). My website, however, is very new, and I never have more than 10-20 online visitors, so high load is out of the question.

I have also done some stress tests locally and the issue does not appear. The issue only appears on my production server (that runs 24/7), which made me think it could be that mono needs to be restarted once in a while (although I would like to know why this is needed in my case, since my website is still very low-profile). For this reason, I set up a auto restart time of two hours for mono. Even after this the problem still showed up (although less frequently).

Then, I immediately thought of configuring MonoMaxActiveRequests and MonoMaxWaitingRequests, but the truth is I have no idea whether these values should be low or high in order to avoid the problem I'm facing. I also don't understand why the MonoMaxWaitingRequests default value is only 20. Does that mean that 40 simultaneous requests is all my server can handle, since the wait line can't go beyond 20?

Overall, my question(s) is(are): Am I doing something wrong or is there still an issue with mod mono? How can I know what values are sane for MonoMaxActiveRequests and MonoMaxWaitingRequests? Should I be increasing these values or reducing them to avoid the reported issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

MonoMaxActiveRequests and MonoMaxWaitingRequests make this value 0.

and set MonoAutoRestartMode Request 1000